# how does phunit process several files regarding requires/includes?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm calling `phpunit` with the argument being a directory (bonus questions: why can't it accept a list of files?) and it's now complaining about a class being declared more than once because of a file included in the *previous* test!

If i run `phpunit firstTest.php; phpunit secondTest.php` everything works

But `phpunit ./` fails with `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class X`

my tests are basically:

```
include 'class_to_be_tested.php'
class class1Test extends...
```

and nothing else. And i'm using the option `--process-isolation`. I could add `require_once`  on my classes, but that's not what i want to be able to test them individually.

shouldn't phpunit follow best testing practices and run one test, clear whatever garbage it have, run another test on a clean state? or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way phpUnit works means that all your tests are run in the context of a single php program. phpUnit aims to isolate the tests from each other, but they are all run within the same program execution.

PHP's `include` statement will include the requested file regardless of whether it has been included before. This means that if you `include` a given class twice, you will get an error the second time. This is happening in your tests because each test is including the same file, but without any consideration to whether it's already been included by one of the other tests.

Solutions:

- Wrap your `include` calls with a `if(class_exists('classname'))` so that you don't include the file if the class has already been defined.
- Include the files in a phpUnit bootstrap file instead of in the tests.
- Use `include_once` (or even `require_once`) instead of `include`.
- Stop including files arbitrarily, and start using an autoloader.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `include` rather than `include_once` and there is no other code shown in your question, the cannot redeclare error could also be that you are including the file again somewhere in the code under test.

Assuming that is not the case, there some behind the scenes things that happen with `--process-isolation` that can keep the global class declarations.  This blog post gives more detail: http://matthewturland.com/2010/08/19/process-isolation-in-phpunit/

Basically, you will want to create your own base `TestCase` and override the `run()` method to set the `preserveGlobalState` to `false`.  This should properly allow all your tests to run together.

The base class would look similar to this (taken from the blog post I referred to):

```
class MyTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function run(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult $result = NULL)
    {
       $this->setPreserveGlobalState(false);
       return parent::run($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
include 'class_to_be_tested.php';
class class1Test extends...
```

to be:

```
include_once 'class_to_be_tested.php';
class class1Test extends...
```

In PHP you need to have a Really Good Reason to use the former.

Regarding *why can't it accept a list of files?*, I think the design decision is that you generally don't need to. However you can do it by creating a test suite in the phpunit.xml.dist file, see 
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration